# Loading JSON and filling SVG depends on data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, svg

I want to fill a country depends on how many users are online from this country. I have SVG file which has all countries, and the if for example from Canada I have 5 people online, then script should fill `id="ca` to green.
I storage the Data in a JSON formatted file.

The error I get in the Console is:

`TypeError: svgMap is undefined`

```
var mapElement = svgMap.getElementById(iso).style.fill="#94d31b";
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $.getJSON("results.json", function(data) 
    {
        data = data.iso_countries;
        var map = document.getElementById("blank_map");
        var svgMap = map.contentDocument;

        for(var key in data)
        {
            var iso = data[key].country;
            var visitors = data[key].visitors;

            if( visitors > 1 && 50>=visitors)
            {
                var mapElement = svgMap.getElementById(iso).style.fill="#94d31b";
            }
            else if( visitors > 50 && 500>=visitors)
            {
                document.getElementById("iso").style.fill="#94d31b";
            }
        }   

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you will have an easier time if you use d3.js to generate an SVG instead of JQuery. See this example, similar to what you would like to do. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5912673

Comment: but this is my SVG http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:BlankMap-World8.svg I just want to load SVG, and change countries color depends on how many users are from country :P so I should just get DOM of this SVG, and then from this SVG get ID of a country and fill with a new color.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of your work. I'm guessing something basic is wrong, like being unable to find the div blank_map or it doesn't have contentDocument there ?

Comment: @lan http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1c/BlankMap-World8.svg - this is my SVG, and this is how I add SVG <embed src="media/map-svg/blank-map.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="blank_map" />

Answer (score 0):

Your need NameSpace for javascript, to handle tags to append new tags o update tags

```
 function Text(){
      //svg is a google chart
      var svg = document.getElementById('graphic').getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];  
      var parent = svg.contentDocument;
      //show me structure svg as DOM
      console.log(parent);

      //find tag fill and change color and write element type text

for(var i=0; i<svg.childNodes[4].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childElementCount; i++) {
    var g = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
    var text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');  
    var child = svg.childNodes[4].firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild; 
    text.setAttribute('x', child.getAttribute('x'));
    text.setAttribute('y', child.getAttribute('y'));
    text.setAttribute('fill', '#000000');
    text.setAttribute('dy', '-2');      
    text.textContent = 'Hell0'; 
    parent.removeChild(child);
    g.appendChild(child);   
    g.appendChild(text);
    parent.appendChild(g);
}

}
```

I hope that it help you

Comment: I don't get it... Now I get "ReferenceError: evt is not defined
svgDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;"